# concatenating two chars in functions and return for output in c++

Tags: c++

Here's an issue in my program.

I have to write a poker game that I have to show the hands of 5 cards.

I constructed a '''Card''' class and `Hand` class that present 5 cards and show it in `main`.

So I have to retrieve suit "Spade" and number "4" from the Card class.

"S4"

I have to retrieve 5 cards to present like this in `main`:

`S4 D6 H3 D7 H9`

So I first try to combine char 'S' and char '4' to form a char* from Card class:

```
char* Card::get_Property() {

    char* str_Suit = new char(suit);      // Load in 'S'
    char* str_Digit = new char(digit);    // Load in '4'
    char* combined = { '\0' };
    strcpy(combined, str_Suit);
    strcat(combined, str_Digit);          // Should be "S4"

    return combined;
}
```

The returned "Combined supposed to be `S4` and send to a hand class for storage:

```
// handCards[] is the initialized Card class

const char* Hand::show() {
    char* temp = { '\0' };

    temp = handCards[0].get_Property();
    for (int j = 1; j < 5; j++) {
        strcat(temp, " ");
        strcat(temp, handCards[j].get_Property());
    }

    const char* output = temp;

    return output;
}
```

In main will be called like this:

```
Hand hand;

cout << hand.show();
```

However, instead of combining suit and digit **(both char)**, the debugger said the memory didn't allocate correctly and both char disappeared.

I tried many methods and searched on stackoverflow and the result remains the same.

How can I allocate the memory or other ways to fix this problem?

Comment: Is the a C or a C++ question? The answers are very different and it looks like you're trying to use C functions with C++ classes? If you're using C++, look at std::string

Comment: Suguest you replace all instances of c-string(s) (`char *`) with `std::string`.  The code is full of memory leaks and buffer overruns.  Correcting it would need a complete re-write.

Comment: Indeed, I did use c++. I tried std::string for concatenation, same problem, i don't know why

Comment: @ThomasDaNerd - trying writing this without using char, or new, or str[anything] funcitons. You should be able to do this with only using std::string and functions it has.

Comment: The shown code shows misunderstanding of C++ fundamentals. This is C++, and not C, and it is not Java. `get_Property()` is leaking memory like a sieve. There is absolutely no reason whatsoever to use `new` for anything done here. The shown code should be using proper, modern, C++ `std::string` classes to easily handle string manipulations like this. `get_Property` should simply be returning a `std::string`, and the rest of the code should use proper modern C++, instead of prehistoric C library string functions like `strcpy` and `strcat`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thankyou for your explaination. And I changed all the ```char*``` and the rest into std::string. However at main, ```cout << show()``` is error and the compiler simply said said can't do it. I don't know why.

Comment: Unfortunately, nobody will tell you why, without seeing a [mre] for the compilation error. You change your code in some unspecified way -- all you provided was a very description of what you changed -- and that results in some compilation error. How can you expect someone else to tell you the reason for the compilation error, when the exact compilation error is not given, and the actual code that results in that compilation error is not shown?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return a `std::string`. Example

```
std::string Card::get_Property() {
    return std::string(1, suit) + digit;
}
```

Or, if you use abseil:

```
return absl::StrCat(suit, digit);
```

---

Problems with your attempt:

> ```
> char* combined = { '\0' };
> ```

This is simply ill-formed. A `char*` cannot be initialised by a `char` because there is no implicit conversion between these types.

> ```
> strcpy(combined, str_Suit);
> ```

The behaviour is undefined because `str_Suit` doesn't points to a null terminated string, which is a pre-condition of `strcpy`.

> ```
> strcat(combined, str_Digit);
> ```

Behaviour is undefined because neither argument points to null terminated string.

Also, the program leaks memory, since you didn't `delete` `str_Suit` nor `str_Digit`, nor did you `std::free` the result of `strcat`.

Comment: but suit and digit are char, unable to convert

Comment: Hi, i used your method, it actually work. However the ```cout << show()``` shows error. I don't know why